# Permisos de visitante/usuario

Tags: php, mysqli, sesiones

Genere la siguiente *comparación* :

```
   <?php
      if($_SESSION['id_nivel'] == 1 || 2){
        ?>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <select name="cantidad" class="form-control">
    <option class="form-control" value="1">1</option>
    <option class="form-control" value="2">2</option>
    <option class="form-control" value="3">3</option>
    <option class="form-control" value="4">4</option>
    <option class="form-control" value="5">5</option>
          </select>
      </div>
          <input name="id_producto" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $columnas["id_producto"];?>">
          <div class="col-md-6" id="carrito">
         <button type="submit" id="boton-add" class="btn bg-lim white" alt="Agregar al carrito" title="Agregar al carrito"> 
           Añadir al carrito <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </button>
      </div>
      <?php 
    } else{
       echo '<div class"col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-6 col-lg-6 col-lx-6>
      <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createacc">Crear Cuenta</a> o 
       <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login">Iniciar Sesión</a>       
     </div>';
    }
      ?>
```

Pero genera el siguiente *notice*:

`Notice: Undefined index: id_nivel`

Entiendo que es porque no se establece un **id_nivel** a la **$_SESSION** ya que no esta registrada, es decir, al crear un usuario se establece **id_usuario** y **id_nivel** entonces, se puede generar la verificación de ambas partes.

> **Aclaración**: Pense este método de ocultar el botón: Añadir al Carrito, ya que cuando no se registra un id_nivel o usuario, al apretar Añadir al Carrito genera errores de faltantes de $variables etc..

---

**Mi pregunta**:

¿Cómo detecto si una *$_SESSION* tiene o no id_nivel?

Es decir:

id_nivel = 1 (Administrador) || 2 (Usuario)

Sin nivel: Visita;

Comment: `if($_SESSION['id_nivel'] == 1 || 2){` es bastante curioso porque creo que te va a funcionar para lo que quieres, pero es potencialmente peligroso porque no hace lo que tú crees que hace (o esa es la impresión que me da). Quieres que se entre en la condición si el id_nivel es 1 o 2, pero por la precedencia de operadores lo que se va a hacer `$_SESSION['id_nivel'] == 1` por un lado y  `2` por le otro con el operador `||`. Independientemente de lo que sea `$_SESSION['id_nivel'] == 1`, en PHP `2` se va a considerar verdad siempre, por lo que siempre se va a entrar en la condición.

Comment: Rectifico: no va a funcionar para lo que quieres, porque como la condición siempre será verdad, entonces todos los usuarios, logueados o no y del nivel que sean entrarán en el `if`.

Comment: Haz una prueba simple: en un fichero .php simplemente pon `<?php $variable=6; if ($variable == 1 || 2) { echo "Es verdad"; }`. El resultado será "Es verdad" aunque `$variable` no sea ni 1 ni 2.

Comment: Con `isset()`pasa igual?

Comment: No, con `isset` no pasa igual, con la solución por la que has optado (acabo de ver tu respuesta) no vas a tener ese problema. Sólo apuntaba a un fallo que podía ocurrir en el código de la pregunta.

Comment: Entiendo. Si por eso opte por utilizar `isset()`ya que la otra comparación siempre daba "Es verdad" como en tu ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pude solucionarlo con `isset()`

Dejo el codigo:

```
      <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['id_nivel'])){
        ?>
    <form>
      <div class="btn-group cart ">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <select name="cantidad" class="form-control">
    <option class="form-control" value="1">1</option>
    <option class="form-control" value="2">2</option>
    <option class="form-control" value="3">3</option>
    <option class="form-control" value="4">4</option>
    <option class="form-control" value="5">5</option>
          </select>
      </div>
  <input name="id_producto" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $columnas["id_producto"];?>">
          <div class="col-md-6" id="carrito">
        <button type="submit" id="boton-add" class="btn bg-lim white" alt="Agregar al carrito" title="Agregar al carrito">
          Añadir al carrito <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </button>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </form>

      <?php 
      }
    else {
      echo '<div class"col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-6 col-lg-6 col-lx-6>Debes estar <a style="cursor:pointer;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createacc">registrado</a> para comprar. ¿Ya tienes una cuenta? <a style="cursor:pointer;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login">Iniciar Sesión</a></div>';
        }
      ?>
```

Se soluciono de esta manera ya que el **visitante** al ingresar no se le establece ningún `id_nivel` (solamente a usuarios) entonces al no poseer `id_nivel`ejecuta el `else`

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer esto al registrar el visitante, si necesitas más parámetros debes agregarlos.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["id_nivel"] = 3; 

Luego validas así   

if(isset($_SESSION['id_nivel'])) //Validar si existe la sesión
    {
       //Si existe la sesión
        if($_SESSION['id_nivel'] == 1 || 2)
        {
           //Es usuario o admin
        }
        else{
           //Es visitante
        }
    }
    else{
        /*
         * No existe sesión y por lo tanto no puedes
         * obtener el el parámetro id_nivel
         * a menos que envíes al session_start
         * y registres los parámetros que un usuario
         * al estar conectado necesita
         */         

    }
```

Comment: Lo implemente y aun asi sigue apareciendo el boton "Añadir Carrito"  intente poniendo cualquier tipo de código en el primer `else{}` // en el visitante, y aun así seguía tomando el `if de ==1 || 2` . Tambien agregue en el ultimo else, sino existe ninguna session que redireccione o directamente no haga nada. Pero de igual manera aparece como lo dicho previamente, y la idea es ocultar el boton de carrito del nivel=3.

Comment: De hecho en tu respuesta no necesitas el !ISSET, para eso el else hace revisión del caso contrario a la primera condición pactada.

Comment: se me habia cortado la luz y no pude actualizar la respuesta. Ya esta actualizada.